# how to check dynamic Condition On Dynamic Table using dbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm new To all Of this in my project i use dbcontext and generic Repository along .Net core 5 and dotnet frameWork 5.0.17

now here what I'm traying to do is Store a Condition in string format in sql server like

> Employee.Id==2

in my mind 1st of all I must retrieve Employee  then with help of predicate apply condition in where clause
and I'm stuck in find solution for 1st step
any hint or solution is appreciated.

Comment: What is your 1st step want to do?

Comment: accessing dbset in dbContext?

Comment: hmmm, I think you need learn get started about ef core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/ and then learn how to crud in mvc project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0